# Regex to match name prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex conditions that matches any string  satisfying the following condition:

1. String  starts with the prefix Mr., Mrs., Ms., Dr., or Er.

I tried `/(?<!prefix )Mr.[a-zA-Z]/` so far, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\.[a-zA-Z]+`

Explanation:

- `(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)` - uses grouping and alternation to match any of the following: `Mr`, `Mrs`, `Ms`, `Dr`, `Er`
- `\.` - matches the literal `.` character
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - matches one or more occurence of an uppercase/lowercase letter.

```js
const regex = /(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Er)\.[a-zA-Z]+/;

function validate(str){
  console.log(`${str} matches regex? ${regex.test(str)}`)
}

validate("Mr.John")
validate("Mrs.John")
validate("Ms.John")
validate("Dr.John")
validate("Er.John")
validate("Spectric.Spectric")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked
had to use this /^ to use as prefix

Answer (score 0):

To match all variants you can write the pattern as:

```
^(?:Mrs?|Ms|[DE]r)\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Spx3A/1)

If there has to be a char A-Za-z following, you could also match optional whitespace chars preceding the character class

```
^(?:Mrs?|Ms|[DE]r)\.\s*[A-Za-z]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gPvmbT/1)